# Why was my question closed as homework, and what can I do?

Tags: support

I'd like to preface this question with the information that I'm not a student, and my question just arose from curiosity. I searched on Google and I found no answer, so I posted my question here.

This is the question:
[Why Bactrian camels has two humps and dromedary one?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/111930/75227)

Why is it considered homework and what can I do now?

Answer (score 2):

We want questions that show some research effort: indicate what you've read and where in trying to solve your question, or where it originated.

Links or references to sources are great; it's of course okay if you don't find an answer, but questions are best when they come with surrounding context.

You can edit your question to add these things.

Comment: @MarcoSulla to follow-up: I encourage you to provide this additional context (i.e., where you've looked and what you learned) as editing your closed post will trigger a "reopen" vote -- potentially allowing your post to be reopened and answered. Thanks for your effort and participation here!

Comment: @theforestecologist what do you think now? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/111930/why-bactrian-camels-has-two-humps-and-dromedary-one

Comment: @MarcoSulla Google is just a search engine. Linking to it is only marginally better than simply saying "I searched for an answer". Linking to a google search gives us a starting point to know what you searched, but it doesn't actually indicate what sources you've looked at nor what you specifically learned from each source. Which specific sites did you look at? Cite/link to them specifically indicating what they taught you (and what remains unfound). [In the end, we're not an answering service. We're a learning community. We're looking for more effort/participation from the question posters].